# Change screen to sub-directory using Tree Apache Wicket

Tags: java, tree, wicket

I would like to use Tree Apache Wicket to implement the following opeation:

- Top folders will be showed on the main screen(etc..Folder A, Forder B..and so on).
- Once the user has clicked on a folder, instead of expanding the subdirectories, he will be taken to another screen which have the previously clicked folder as the main directory.
- The user only can only use a link to return back to the previous level of directory.

How can I make it possible to re-populate the tree wicket every time the screen changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the Tree junction link behavior. On click you have to use something like setResponsePage(theNewPageThatKnowsItsRootNode) or setResponsePage(ThePage.class, pageParametersThatBringTheNewRootNodeName).